# Python file wrapper, best design?

Tags: python, file, inheritance, io, wrapper

I need to parse a domain specific configuration file, but before I begin pulling the gold out of it, I want to remove the comments.

Once comments are removed, I still want to be able to use things like `getline()`, `seek()` and `tell()`

(the offsets in seeking due to large chunks removed is fine because all parsing is encapsulated within a single parsing object)

**Inherit from `file` ?:**

My first thought was to create an object like `MyFile(file)`, and override `__init__` to create a `self.content` string, then override everything with file access... but it looked far too tricky (I saw many forum posts of people having trouble trying this)

**Delegate to `file` object ?:**

Create a `MyFile(file)` class that creates a `file` class, and delegate calls from the `MyFile` instance to the internal `file` instance.
This makes sense if the calls to `MyFile` expect a return beyond the comment find/replace search parameters...
for example: `getline()` would be fine for single-line comments, but for a file where the 1st 3 lines form a single block comment, `getline()` `getline()` isn't going to work without a lot of messy code
(not to mention keeping track of `seek()` offsets)

**Re-create in temporary file?:**

Finally, I felt like I was taking the lazy option in parsing the whole file, then re-saving it as a temporary file... then returning a file-handle to that (demo code below)

```
import re
import tempfile

FILE_NAME = 'some_file.ldf'

# ideal case
fh = open(FILE_NAME)

# my example

def getHandle(self, filename, mode='r'):
    # ----- Remove comments -----
    with open(filename, mode=mode) as fh:
        content = fh.read()
    # remove /* ... */ comment blocks
    content = re.sub(re.compile(r'/\*.*?\*/', re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE), '', content, re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
    # remove // ... line comments
    content = re.sub(r'//.*', '', content)

    # ----- Write to Temporary File -----
    fh = tempfile.TemporaryFile()
    fh.write(content)
    fh.seek(0)

fh = getHandle(FILE_NAME)
```

**Better Design?:**

Does anybody have a better design for this?...
or even a completely different angle on this sort of problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly it sounds like your DSL parser may be the problem here. Basically if you've designed a DSL, it should include the recognition of comments and just ignore them.

Taking the route of writing this as a file filter is an interesting but complex for the sake of complexity - it's just covering up for the fact that your DSL parser is incomplete.

Depending on how you've written your parser this may be easy, or not so easy to fix. But, take this pyparsing example of a verilog parser. It simply has the definition of cStyleComment and tells the parser to just ignore them completely. No muss, no fuss.

http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/view/verilogParse.py/241112725/verilogParse.py

Comment: thanks synthesizerpatel!, you're totally right, I've been looking at it at the wrong level... I (PS: I didn't design the DSL, I'm just parsing it.... if it were mine, it would just have been in XML, but that doesn't change your observations.)... I've finished my work on this now, and I've got to move on to other tasks, but I'll definitely spend some time getting to know `pyparsing`... thank you ;)

Comment: Pyparsing is no longer hosted on wikispaces.com. Go to https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing